# Using openCV java on mac with intellij

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, jar, homebrew

I'm trying to use openCV in my java project, because it's a separate package, I need to add it using a jar file. I'm trying to follow this guide to integrate it into the intellij IDE https://medium.com/@aadimator/how-to-set-up-opencv-in-intellij-idea-6eb103c1d45c

But the guide is either outdated or not designed for a version of openCV installed with mac  homebrew. The guide tells me the jar file and native libraries can be found under `opencv/build/java/`

But this looks nothing like the directory structure I have. The closest thing I can find is `opencv/4.3.0/share/java`

I tried to add the jar file from there to my intellij IDE as a module, but when I try to run some test openCV code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int, double, double, double, double)'
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:77)
    at RGBParser.testOpenCV(RGBParser.java:42)
    at RGBParser.makeSynopsis(RGBParser.java:260)
    at Layout.<init>(Layout.java:94)
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

From this error, my guess is that I didn't link the native extensions properly, because I don't add the jar file at all, the compiler throws a different error that says the package can't be found:

```
Error:(13, 23) java: package org.opencv.core does not exist
```

My goal is be able to run java code that uses openCV classes, such as in this code snippet:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

public static void testOpenCV() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
    Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
    Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
    mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
    Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
    mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data:\n" + m.dump());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` in my test code solved this issue.